# Why does Windows 10 report its version as 6.3?

Tags: windows, registry, windowsversion

Im working on a Wix installer and need to know the windows version, however, on Windows 10 when I check the registry 'CurrentVersion' located at:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

It reports 6.3 which is Windows 8.1 and not 10

Why is this and how can I differentiate Windows 8.1 & 10?

Comment: You upgraded from 8.1 to 10: http://superuser.com/q/962796/4206

Comment: @ Roger Lipscombe Yes I saw that post but I didn't upgrade this is a fresh install on a VM

Comment: Microsoft got fed-up with installers checking the version number, and failing, even though their new version was quite capable of running the app.  So they did not change the registry key value.  These version lies are universal in the api as well.  I suppose you could look if CurrentMajorVersionNumber exists.

Comment: @ Hans Passant Ok so what is the correct way to check the OS version?

Comment: @ Hans Passant you read my mind with your edit thanks.